# no me toma el some

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando utilizar el método `some()` en una variable pero no la toma. Me lo toma como indefinido y no entiendo el error, no se si alguien me podría ayudar. El `some()` de `producotsEnCarrito` es el que no me toma. Y luego, también me salta error en donde dice `productoAgregado.cantidad` diciendo que esta indefinido.

```
function agregarAlCarrito(e) {
const idBoton = e.currentTarget.id  
const productoAgregado = productos.find(producto => producto.id === idBoton)

if (productosEnCarrito.some(producto => producto.id === idBoton)) {
    productosEnCarrito.findIndex(producto => producto.id === idBoton)
}else{
    productoAgregado.cantidad = 1
    productosEnCarrito.push(productoAgregado)
}

actualizarCarrito()

localStorage.setItem("productos-en-carrito", JSON.stringify(productosEnCarrito))
}
```

Comment: No hay sufuciente código para ver tu error, evidentemente no encuentra la lista de `productosEnCarrito` y tampoco encuentra el producto en la lista `productos`. Por otro lado te recomiendo un pequeño cambio, en lugar de ocupar `some` + `findeIndex`, esas 2 búsquedas se pueden reemplazar por un solo `find`

Comment: ProductosEnCarrito es un simple array vacio no tiene nada mas

Comment: `some` no da problema con un array vacío, tu problema está en otro lado, por eso debes colocar un [MRE] donde se muestre el error que describes